# Google apps script not clearing previous results

Tags: google-apps-script

I have wrote a simple apps script that outputs some data to the log, the problem is that it's still showing previous data that should not be there as I have removed the labels that it refers to on those emails.  I'm no expert but it almost seems like a cache issue that needs to be cleared somewhere.

Here is my script:

```
function getGmailEmails()
{
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('IZ/IZadd')
  var threads = label.getThreads()
  var grandTotal = 0;
  for(var i = threads.length - 1; i >=0; i--)
  {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages()
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++)
    {
      var message = messages[j]
      var extract = extractDetails(message)
      grandTotal += extract.total
      Logger.log('' + (j+1) +'          Amount: ' + extract.total + '      Study:  ' + extract.matches)
    }
    //threads[i].removeLabel(label)
  }
  Logger.log('Grand Total:      ' + grandTotal)
}

function extractDetails(message)
{
  var pattern1 = /\d{1}\.\d{2}(?= USD. )/g
  var pattern2 = /(?!study )[A-Za-z0-9]+(?=. Hope)/g
  var bodyContents = message.getPlainBody()
  var usd = bodyContents.match(pattern1)
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < usd.length; i++) 
  {
    total += parseFloat (usd[i])
  }
  var study = bodyContents.match(pattern2)

  return {
    total: total, matches: study
  }
}
```

Here is the output in the log:

2:44:46 PM  Notice  Execution started
2:44:48 PM  Info    1          Amount: 8      Study:  C1426S209
2:44:48 PM  Info    2          Amount: 8      Study:  C952S6087
2:44:48 PM  Info    3          Amount: 8      Study:  C1024S350
2:44:48 PM  Info    4          Amount: 8      Study:  C1627S134
2:44:48 PM  Info    5          Amount: 8      Study:  C841S3846
2:44:48 PM  Info    6          Amount: 8      Study:  C920S3525
2:44:48 PM  Info    7          Amount: 8      Study:  C902S3849
2:44:48 PM  Info    8          Amount: 8      Study:  C5067S7299
2:44:48 PM  Info    9          Amount: 8      Study:  C5067S7299
2:44:48 PM  Info    10          Amount: 8      Study:  C944S391
2:44:48 PM  Info    11          Amount: 8      Study:  C1280S146
2:44:48 PM  Info    Grand Total:      88
2:44:47 PM  Notice  Execution completed

Numbers 1 - 7 should not be on this list as they are from yesterdays log and I have removed the labels on those emails but they are still showing in this latest log.

Can anyone help please.

I tried to clear my Gmail cache and also clear the log but this did not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about what you need but you can clean GAS Logger by using
Logger.clear()
If thats the issue simply place that line at the beggining of Your function and thats it

Comment: I already tried that I mentioned it in my op.  This did not work.